# Incrementing SQL column during UPDATE

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

My user_account table contains a column I created called donation_coins.

Whenever I execute the UPDATE query to set donation_coins a new value, it just deletes the old value and rewrite to the amount that has been defined in the donation process.

eg. If x had 10 donation_coins and donated again for 15 coins, his donation_coins will be 15 instead of 25.

The field type is INT with NULLS enabled.

This is the Code

```
connectdb($CONFIG['dbdbname'], $CONFIG['dbaddress'], $CONFIG['dbuser'], $CONFIG['dbpass']);

$query = mssql_query("SELECT * FROM user_account WHERE account = '".$account_username."'");
$row10 = mssql_fetch_array($query);

$old_coins = $row10['donation_coins'];
$transered_coins = $coin_quanity_coin;
$new_coins = $old_coins - $transered_coins;

//mssql_query("UPDATE [lin2db].[dbo].[user_account] SET [donation_coins] = '".$new_coins."' WHERE account = '".$account_username."'");
mssql_query("UPDATE [lin2db].[dbo].[user_account] SET [donation_coins] = donation_coins - ".$coin_quanity_coin." WHERE account = '".$account_username."'");
```

Comment: perhaps you should share your query/code.

Comment: yup sorry, updated question.

Comment: Reading your code above, I see in the UPDATE .. SET donation_coins = donation_coins MINUS $coin_quanity_coin.  What and where are you getting $coin_quanity_coin?

Answer (score 4):

Do it like this

```
update your_table
set x = x + 15
where id = :someId
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it if > SQL Server 2005

```
update user_account
set donation_coins += 15
where id = @someid
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to provide the new coins for the update statement

```
mssql_query("UPDATE [lin2db].[dbo].[user_account] SET [donation_coins] = ".$new_coins." WHERE account = '".$account_username."'");
```

You just calculated the new amount before your sql execution.

Cheers,
Martin